# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli boolean given while inserting unicode data to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to insert unicode data to database so user the function `$mysqli=mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf-8');` what is wrong with it?
 I couldn't solve this.

```
function insert(){

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_darta');
    $mysqli=mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf-8');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    }
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into tbl_darta (fiscal_year, darta_no, darta_date, patra_date, paper_from, letter_recievedby, subject, file_upload, remarks, created_by, created_date, section) values ('$this->fiscal_year', '$this->darta_no', '$this->darta_date', '$this->patra_date', '$this->paper_from', '$this->letter_recievedby', '$this->subject', '$this->file_upload', '$this->remarks','$this->created_by','$this->created_date','$this->section')");
}
```

Comment: What's the error message in it's entirety?

Comment: from where you are getting these values   mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into tbl_darta (fiscal_year, darta_no, darta_date, patra_date, paper_from, letter_recievedby, subject, file_upload, remarks, created_by, created_date, section) values ('$this->fiscal_year', '$this->darta_no', '$this->darta_date', '$this->patra_date', '$this->paper_from', '$this->letter_recievedby', '$this->subject', '$this->file_upload', '$this->remarks','$this->created_by','$this->created_date','$this->section')");

Comment: @Wzakm10 check the answer. Just replace my insert function definition with new one. Still faces issue let me know.

Comment: And add mysqli tag in your question.So that you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your query you passing argument which Return Value:    TRUE on success. FALSE on failure.**

mysqli_query({database connection object}, {your desired query})

```
    function insert(){

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db_darta');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); // returns true or false
    mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl_darta (fiscal_year, darta_no, darta_date, patra_date, paper_from, letter_recievedby, subject, file_upload, remarks, created_by, created_date, section) values ('$this->fiscal_year', '$this->darta_no', '$this->darta_date', '$this->patra_date', '$this->paper_from', '$this->letter_recievedby', '$this->subject', '$this->file_upload', '$this->remarks','$this->created_by','$this->created_date','$this->section')");
}
```